# Sistema de login com níveis de permissão

Tags: php, session

Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema de login com níveis de permissão, entretanto, na hora de logar como administrador, numa página que adm teria permissão para entrar, a permissão é negada.
 É como se a minha SESSION estivesse null, ao invés de o adm ser redirecionado para o index.html, aparece um echo com PERMISSÃO NEGADA. 
Eu segui o seguinte [tutorial](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/como-criar-um-sistema-de-login-com-niveis-de-permissao), mas o resultado não saiu de acordo com o esperado, que era: ao logar como adm, ser redirecionado para index.html. Sim, eu estou pegando os dados certos do form do html. Qual o possível erro?

```
<?php
// The session must be started on each different page
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

$nivel_necessario = 1;

// Checks if there is a session variable that identifies the user
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario']) OR ($_SESSION['tipo'] < $nivel_necessario)){

// Destroys session per security
session_destroy();

// Redirects the visitor back pro login
echo "PERMISSÃO NEGADA";
//header("Location: login.html"); exit;

}else{
    header("Location: ../../index.html"); exit;
}
?>

<h1>Restricted page</h1>
Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?>!
```

Código da consulta que me retorna o usuário e o tipo

```
$query = "SELECT usuario, senha, tipo FROM usuario WHERE usuario='".$usuario."' AND senha='".$codificada."'";
$rs = mysqli_query($db, $query);
print_r($rs);
if($rs->num_rows!=0){

    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado['usuario'];
    echo "string";
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $resultado['senha'];
    $_SESSION['tipo'] = $resultado['tipo'];

    // Redireciona o visitante
    header("Location: restrito.php"); exit;
    //header("Location: ../../index.html");

}else{
   echo "Usuário/senha não encontrado";
}
```

Código da tabela que os dados são guardados

```
CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `instituicao` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
<?php
session_start();

$nivel_necessario = 1;

// Checks if there is a session variable that identifies the user
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario']) OR ($_SESSION['tipo'] < $nivel_necessario)){

// Destroys session per security
unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
unset($_SESSION['tipo']);

// Redirects the visitor back pro login
echo "PERMISSÃO NEGADA";
//header("Location: login.html"); exit;

}else{
    header("Location: ../../index.html"); exit;
}
?>

<h1>Restricted page</h1>
Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?>!
```

Outro código

```
<?php
session_start();
$query = "SELECT usuario, senha, tipo FROM usuario WHERE usuario='".$usuario."' AND senha='".$codificada."'";
$rs = mysqli_query($db, $query);
print_r($rs);
if($rs->num_rows!=0){

    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);


    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado['usuario'];
    echo "string";
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $resultado['senha'];
    $_SESSION['tipo'] = $resultado['tipo'];

    // Redireciona o visitante
    header("Location: restrito.php"); exit;
    //header("Location: ../../index.html");

}else{
   echo "Usuário/senha não encontrado";
}
```